# Seaborn Box and Whisker plot, X and Y labels, making it bold?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

```
sns.boxplot(x=df['NAME'], y=df['QTY'], showmeans=True, meanprops={"marker":"o",
                       "markerfacecolor":"red", 
                       "markeredgecolor":"black",
                      "markersize":"2"})
```

Above is the code line to create a Boxplot in Seaborn.

1. Just wondering if anyone knows how to make X-axis label (NAME) and Y-axis label (QTY) appear "Bold" on the chart. I don't wanna be adding a new line of code with X and Y labels as both values might change time to time. There gotta be a way to insert 'fontweight = 'bold' in that line somewhere.
2. Also, if there's a way to rotate X axis values (all the names) to 90 degrees. They all appear horizontal.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ax = sns.boxplot(...)` to catch the subplot on which the plot is created. Then `ax.get_xlabel()` returns the existing x-label which can be used to set it again an update its properties. There is no way to include all this in the `sns.boxplot()` command itself.

Similarly, the orientation of the tick labels can be changed via  `ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=...)`. Note that `plt.tightlayout()` will fit the labels nicely into the surrounding plot.

Here is some example code using the standard titanic dataset:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
ax = sns.boxplot(x=df['class'], y=df['age'], showmeans=True,
                 meanprops={"marker": "o", "markerfacecolor": "red", "markeredgecolor": "black", "markersize": "2"})
ax.set_xlabel(ax.get_xlabel(), fontdict={'weight': 'bold'})
ax.set_ylabel(ax.get_ylabel(), fontdict={'weight': 'bold'})
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.boxplot with change xlabel properties and tick rotation]

Comment: It actually didn't work on a dataset that was already loaded into RAM. With the CSV file called "IRIS" and "df" was loading selective columns from that CSV file.

Comment: *"it didn't work"* isn't very informative.  Did it crash? Did you get an error? Did something unexpected happen? Was something missing in the plot? Did you forget to catch the `ax` in `ax = sns.boxplot(....)`? ...?  Maybe you could [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70518472/edit) your post and add more information? Could you add the actual code that you used? Does my example code work for you?

Comment: Thank you for providing the earlier comment. The catch wasn't executed properly. I spotted the issue. Fixed it. It works nicely now.